# How do you Determine the Fastest Vibrational Mode of a Crystal?

Tags: frequency, crystals, vibrations, phonons, molecular-dynamics

I understand that a crystal's vibrational modes are Phonons and have a minimum wavelength that is limited by twice the equilibrium separation between neighbouring atoms. But I don't understand how you can calculate the "fastest vibrational mode" or if that's even the correct way to describe it. Should it be the "highest frequency phonon"?

How is this value typically calculated?

I'd like to know this for Molecular Dynamics simulations, as I'm modelling crystals and need to set the time step low enough to capture all possible atomic vibrations.

Comment: ‘Fast’ has issues differentiating between frequency and propagation velocity. You appear to want the first, but it is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I would like the first, do you have any idea how it's usually calculated?